# Installing ruby19 with +nosuffix still leaves the suffix

Tags: ruby, macports

Following the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333569/how-does-macports-install-packages-how-can-i-activate-a-ruby-installation-done) found in many places, I tried to install Ruby 1.9 without a suffix using this command:

```
sudo port install ruby19 +nosuffix
```

This still leaves the suffix "1.9" on the binary; typing `which ruby` yields `/usr/bin/ruby` (the system installation); in Macports' */opt/local/bin*, there is only the file *ruby1.9* to be found.

This is on a system with a fresh installation of Macports. No error messages or warnings during the execution of the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently noticed the same thing. It seems that the `ruby19` port no longer supports the `+nosuffix` variant, and the `port` tool seems to silently ignore it if you try to use it. The [MacPorts ruby19 package information page](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/ruby19/Portfile) seems to confirm this.

EDIT:

After posting, I took a second look at the portfile description and there may be a new syntax at work:

`sudo port select ruby ruby19`

This seems to have created all of the necessary symlinks.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the [MacPorts guide](http://guide.macports.org/) makes absolutely no mention of the `select` command, but `port help select` does provide some shallow reference.

Comment: The `sudo port select ruby ruby19` did the trick!